# How to do a ppa for a java ant project?

Tags: java, ppa

I was doing a launchpad ppa for my ant project using [jdeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb).

when I had the unpleasant surprise in the last step that ubuntu ppa actually builds the package from the repository, not just accepts signed debian files.

> - Is there anyway for me to upload my project without having to use a alien build system for the ubuntu sandbox ?
> - ie: can i call ant in their sandbox ?
> - Also considering that I depend on some (but not all but that is already solved in my ant file) binary jars libraries ?
> - Is it impossible without compiling and including the source of all libraries used that are not in the repositories ?